SSL hash size change before page delivery
I'm trying to make the SSL encryption for everything sha256 instead of sha384 for speed. I notice websites that rank higher than mine use sha256.
I looked at my browser reports and noticed this. (I blocked out the domain and codes)


I also tested my site at SSLlabs and it too is indicating that its simulated clients are receiving encryption in sha384 instead of sha256.
My apache server is setup for TLS1.2 and the relevant config is below:
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA256:ADH-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ADH-AES256-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDH-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDH-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES256-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:ADH-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ADH-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDH-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDH-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on

I have specifically mentioned to honor cipher order (which SSLlabs confirms during tests) however it insists on using sha384 when the 1st entry in my cipher list is ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 which suggests to me that sha256 should be used first instead.
I also have OCSP stapling enabled and when checking that through open SSL, it reports using sha384.
Is there something I'm missing in my apache 2.4.37 config? I want the encoding to the client to be sha256 instead of sha384 for speed.


... it too is indicating that its simulated clients are receiving encryption in sha384 instead of sha256

What you observe is a property of the certificate: the hash algorithm used in the certificates signature. This is relevant only once for certificate validation during the TLS handshake and is not relevant for the encryption of application data. This also means that your cipher settings are irrelevant here.

I also have OCSP stapling enabled and when checking that through open SSL, it reports using sha384.

Also, this has nothing to do with encryption and ciphers.

I want the encoding to the client to be sha256 instead of sha384 for speed.

If you want to know what is used for encryption look at the used cipher, which is a property of the current TLS connection, not a property of the certificate. I think Google Chrome does not show this anymore, but Firefox does.
Note also that this might change depening on the client used since it depends on what the client supports. And with modern clients you'll likely see none of the ciphers you've configured used, since these clients use TLS 1.3 and your currently configured ciphers are relevant only for TLS 1.2 and lower.

One browser I use is firefox 130. It supports my ciphers and also my server cannot handle TLS 1.3 without having to redo the whole operating system thanks to openSSL

I would encourage you to use Mozilla Security recommendations:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS
If you want to support TLS1.3 only, use the Modern Compatibility ciphers. If you require TLS1.2, incorporate Intermediate compatibility ciphers.
For your case, this config allows TLS1.2 and 1.3:
SSLCipherSuite  TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305

This config allows you to:

Prioritize security by not using unsafe ciphers
Prioritize SHA256 ciphers for speed, unless the client supports hardware-accelerated AES (allowing the client to choose)
Reduce your cipher list from 32 to 12, making it much more manageable

